# Understanding context in C# 5 async/await

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, asp.net-4.5, conceptual

Am I correct that async/await itself has nothing to do with concurrency/parallelism and is nothing more than continuation-passing style (CPS) implementation? And the real threading is performed by `SynchronizationContext` instance that `await` passes/restores?

If that is correct I have the following question about `SynchronizationContext`:
it guarantees that a continuation will be executed on the same thread.

However, are there any guaranties that the thread's context information is persisted? I mean `Name`, `CurrentPrincipal`, `CurrentCulture`, `CurrentUICulture`, etc. Does it depend on framework (ASP.NET, WinForms, WCF, WPF)?

Comment: In general, `SynchronizationContext` *does not* guarantee that continuation will be executed on the same thread. Some contexts to that (WPF, Winforms), but others don't (ASP.NET).

Comment: You can set a default culture for threads [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26782711/385995).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> Am i correct that async/await itself has nothing to do with concurrency/parallelism and is nothing more than CPS implementation?

Well, `async` / `await` is a rewriting that uses CPS, so your core understanding is correct.

Regarding "concurrency" and "parallelism", I would say that it does enable concurrency; you can start multiple `async` operations which are all "in flight" at the same time. This is easy to do with `Task.WhenAll` and `Task.WhenAny`.

Also, even though `async` by itself doesn't imply "multithreading", `Task.Run` does enable easy `async`-compatible multithreading

> And the real threading is performed by SynchronizationContext instance that await passes/restores?

Think of it this way: the continuation created by the CPS rewriting has to run *somewhere*. The captured "async context" can be used to schedule the continuation.

Side note: the captured context is actually `SynchronizationContext.Current` *unless it is null*, in which case the captured context is `TaskScheduler.Current`.

Another important note: the capturing and restoring of the context is actually up to the "awaiter" object. So, by default, if you `await` a `Task` (or any other built-in awaitable), the context will be captured and restored. But if you `await` the result of `ConfigureAwait(false)`, then the context is not captured. Similarly, if you `await` your own custom awaitable, it won't capture the context (unless you program it to).

> However, are there any guaranties that the thread's context information is persisted? I mean Name, CurrentPrincipal, CurrentCulture, CurrentUICulture, etc.

`SynchronizationContext` is different than `ExecutionContext`. A simplified answer is that `ExecutionContext` always "flows", so `CurrentPrincipal` flows (if it didn't, it could be a security issue, which is why APIs that don't flow `ExecutionContext` always end in `Unsafe`).

In UI apps, culture doesn't flow, but by default it's the same for all threads anyway. `Name` is definitely not going to flow, unless you resume on the same thread (e.g., using a UI `SynchronizationContext`).

---

For some further reading, I recommend starting with my own [`async` / `await` tutorial](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and then the [official `async` / `await` FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/asyncawait-faq/). Then take a look at [Stephen Toub's blog post on `ExecutionContext` vs. `SynchronizationContext`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/).

You may also find my [`SynchronizationContext` article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/february/msdn-magazine-parallel-computing-it-s-all-about-the-synchronizationcontext) helpful.

Comment: Thanks.  The link to Stephen Toub's blog post on ExecutionContext vs. SynchronizationContext was extremely helpful to me.

Comment: Dude you are all over async.  Like everywhere.  Nice!

Comment: The link to Stephen Toub's post is giving a 403 but I also found it here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/

Answer (score 4):

No, the `async`/`await` keywords have everything to do with concurrency. `async`/`await` basically wrap your method code in to a task and continuation. To see the exact translation that the compiler produces (using the Task Parallel Library) disassemble some code snippet.  This translation of `async`/`await` usage is 'similar' (but not identical!) to the example below

```
async Task<int> TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync()
{
    int hours;
    // . . .
    // Return statement specifies an integer result.
    return hours;
}

// Calls to TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync
Task<int> returnedTaskTResult = TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync();
int intResult = await returnedTaskTResult;
// or, in a single statement
int intResult = await TaskOfTResult_MethodAsync();
```

this is approxiamtely converted to

```
private int Result()
{
    int hours;
    // . . .
    // Return statement specifies an integer result.
    return hours;
}
```

where you wait for the return outside of the method like

```
int? hours = null;
Task<int> task = null;
task = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => Result());
task.ContnueWith(cont => 
{
    // Some task completion checking...
    hours = task.Result;
}, CancellationToken.None, 
   TaskCreationOptions.None, 
   TaskScheduler.Current);
```

Or, you could place the TPL code into the `Result` method

```
private int ResultAsync()
{
    int? hours = null;
    Task<int> task = null;
    task = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => 
    {
        int hours;
        // . . .
        // Return statement specifies an integer result.
        return hours;
    }, CancellationToken.None, 
       TaskCreationOptions.None, 
       TaskScheduler.Current);
    try
    {
        return task.Result;
    }
    catch (AggregateException aggEx)
    {
        // Some handler method for the agg exception.
        aggEx.Handle(HandleException); 
    }
}
```

`SynchronizationContext` does not guarantee that continuation will be executed on the same thread for the `async`/`awate` code. However, you can set the context using TPL code, via the `SynchronisationContex` keyword.