# Set Thread.CurrentPrincipal Asynchronously?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

Using ASP.NET WebAPI, during authentication, `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is set so that controllers can later use the `ApiController.User` property.

If that authentication step becomes asynchronous (to consult another system), any mutation of `CurrentPrincipal` is lost (when the caller's `await` restores the synchronization context).

Here's a very simplified example (in the real code, authentication happens in an action filter):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ExampleAsyncController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
{
    public async Task GetAsync()
    {
        await AuthenticateAsync();

        // The await above saved/restored the current synchronization
        // context, thus undoing the assignment in AuthenticateAsync(). 
        Debug.Assert(User is GenericPrincipal);
    }

    private static async Task AuthenticateAsync()
    {
        // Save the current HttpContext because it's null after await.
        var currentHttpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

        // Asynchronously determine identity.
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        var identity = new GenericIdentity("<name>");

        var roles = new string[] { };
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);
        currentHttpContext.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
    }
}
```

How do you set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` in an async function such that the caller's `await` doesn't discard that mutation when restoring the synchronization context?

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem, but ideally it would be best to authenticate them before the controller is invoked.  In my WebAPI projects, I like to setup a `DelegatingHandler` which does authentication before it gets to the controller.

Comment: @Matthew, I agree and that's how the real code works, an action filter handles the authentication before the controller method is invoked. I excluded the action filter to simplify my example, but the problem is the same in either situation.

Comment: From this stackoverflow answer, it appears if you set CurrentPrincipal it will persist into the calling thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12460170/507793, otherwise I'm not sure how to solve your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using ASP.NET Web API, my ExecutionContext isn't flowing in async actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964244/using-asp-net-web-api-my-executioncontext-isnt-flowing-in-async-actions)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to set `HttpContext.Current.User` as well. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964244/using-asp-net-web-api-my-executioncontext-isnt-flowing-in-async-actions/15972291#15972291) and [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx) for more info.

**Update:** Also ensure you are running on .NET 4.5 and have `UserTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` set to `true`.

Comment: Thank you for you help Stephen. I added setting of `HttpContext.Current.User` (and updated the code in my question), but it doesn't help. The problem is unchanged.

Comment: It is definitely working for me. I create a new WebAPI project with the code above in the ValuesController, and it works just fine. Follow-up questions: are you running on .NET 4.5, and do you have `UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` set to true?

Comment: Setting `UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` to true fixed the problem! Thank you for taking the time to investigate!

Comment: You're welcome! I edited the answer to be more complete. Odd thing is, on my machine it works whether `UTFSC` is set to `true` or `false`. I'm not sure of the exact conditions where `UTFSC` would make a difference, but I'm glad it helped!

Comment: Stephen, after further investigation, it appears that my example only works because `await Task.Delay(1000)` is present. I asked [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16653308) about this specifically. If you have time, I'd appreciate any input you might have.