# Why is an "await Task.Yield()" required for Thread.CurrentPrincipal to flow correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

The code below was added to a freshly created Visual Studio 2012 .NET 4.5 WebAPI project.

I'm trying to assign both `HttpContext.Current.User` and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` in an asynchronous method. The assignment of `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` flows incorrectly unless an `await Task.Yield();` (or anything else asynchronous) is executed (passing `true` to `AuthenticateAsync()` will result in success).

Why is that?

```
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ExampleWebApi.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        public async Task GetAsync()
        {
            await AuthenticateAsync(false);

            if (!(User is MyPrincipal))
            {
                throw new System.Exception("User is incorrect type.");
            }
        }

        private static async Task AuthenticateAsync(bool yield)
        {
            if (yield)
            {
                // Why is this required?
                await Task.Yield();
            }

            var principal = new MyPrincipal();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        }

        class MyPrincipal : GenericPrincipal
        {
            public MyPrincipal()
                : base(new GenericIdentity("<name>"), new string[] {})
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The `await Task.Yield();` can appear anywhere in `AuthenticateAsync()` or it can be moved into `GetAsync()` after the call to `AuthenticateAsync()` and it will still succeed.
- `ApiController.User` returns `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`.
- `HttpContext.Current.User` always flows correctly, even without `await Task.Yield()`.
- `Web.config` includes `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>` which [implies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx) `UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext`.
- I asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16552539) a couple days ago, but did not realize that example was only succeeding because `Task.Delay(1000)` was present.

Comment: What exactly happens if you leave that out?

Comment: @SLaks, If `await Task.Yield()` is skipped, `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` reverts back to what it was before calling `await AuthenticateAsync()`. Since `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is no longer a `MyPrincipal`, the exception is thrown.

Comment: In my Owin middleware, I had to chain in a last piece of middleware that simply does await Task.Yield();
this seems to cause Thread.CurrentPrincipal to be as expected later throughout the execution.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

How interesting! It appears that `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is based on the *logical* call context, not the per-thread call context. IMO this is quite unintuitive and I'd be curious to hear why it was implemented this way.

---

In .NET 4.5., `async` methods interact with the logical call context so that it will more properly flow with `async` methods. I have a [blog post on the topic](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html); AFAIK that's the only place where it's documented. In .NET 4.5, at the beginning of every `async` method, it activates a "copy-on-write" behavior for its logical call context. When (if) the logical call context is modified, it will create a local copy of itself first.

You can see the "localness" of the logical call context (i.e., whether it has been copied) by observing `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ExecutionContextBelongsToCurrentScope` in a watch window.

If you don't `Yield`, then when you set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, you're creating a copy of the logical call context, which is treated as "local" to that `async` method. When the `async` method returns, that local context is discarded and the original context takes its place (you can see `ExecutionContextBelongsToCurrentScope` returning to `false`).

On the other hand, if you do `Yield`, then the `SynchronizationContext` behavior takes over. What actually happens is that the `HttpContext` is captured and used to resume both methods. In this case, you're *not* seeing `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` preserved from `AuthenticateAsync` to `GetAsync`; what is actually happening is [`HttpContext` is preserved, and then `HttpContext.User` is overwriting `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx) before the methods resume.

If you move the `Yield` into `GetAsync`, you see similar behavior: `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is treated as a local modification scoped to `AuthenticateAsync`; it reverts its value when that method returns. However, `HttpContext.User` is still set correctly, and that value will be captured by `Yield` and when the method resumes, it will overwrite `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`.

Comment: Hi! Did you ever heard why this was implemented this way? I have read this post 3 times already and it is still blowing my mind.

Comment: @vtortola: I don't know for sure. I assume it was so that the user permissions would flow to background threads automatically. That was probably done a good decade ago, and the copy-context-on-update behavior is much more recent. So they conflicted in this odd way.