# DelegatingHandler setting CurrentPrincipal

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, mstest

I am trying to unit test an implementation of DelegateHandler. My simplified implementation:

```
public class FooHandler
    : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(
            new GenericIdentity("Vegard"), new[] { "A", "B" });

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

When I try to unit test this, I do it like this:

```
public class TestHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly Func<HttpRequestMessage,
        CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> _handlerFunc;
    public TestHandler()
    {
        _handlerFunc = (r, c) => Return(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _handlerFunc(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> Return(HttpStatusCode status)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => new HttpResponseMessage(status));
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task SendAsync_CorrectTokens_IsAuthorized()
{
    var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://www.test.com");

    var handler = new AuthorizationHeaderHandler
        {
            InnerHandler = new TestHandler()
        };

    var invoker = new HttpMessageInvoker(handler);
    var result = await invoker.SendAsync(message, new CancellationToken());

    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
    Assert.IsTrue(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated); // fails
    Assert.AreEqual("Vegard", Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name); // fails
}
```

My guess is that this happens because `HttpMessageInvoker` runs the `DelegateHandler` on a separate thread. Can I force these to be on the same thread?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I force these to be on the same thread?

You can't.

A better question is "how do I flow `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to whatever thread is executing the request"? There *is* an answer to this question.

`Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is odd in ASP.NET. In fact, I recommend you don't use it at all; use `HttpContext.User` instead. But if you want, you can get it to work by understanding these points:

1. `HttpContext.User` is flowed by the ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext`.
2. `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is overwritten by `HttpContext.User` whenever a thread enters an ASP.NET request `SynchronizationContext`.

Unfortunately, your current test is flawed in a couple of key points:

- After a request is completed, the value of `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is undefined.
- The current way you're running your tests, there is no `HttpContext` (or ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext`), and this interferes with the flowing of the principal user.

To fully test authorization, you'd need an integration test.

Also see [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653308/why-is-an-await-task-yield-required-for-thread-currentprincipal-to-flow-corr/16654386#16654386).

Answer (score 2):

What you're actually running into is the behavior of await. Await will reset the principal to whatever it was when you entered the await when you exit the await. So since there is no current principal when you call await invoker.SendAsync, there will be no current principal after you await that call.

However, your test handler should see the right principal. What you could do is have your test handler store the current principal in its SendAsync implementation, expose it as a public property, and then have your test assert that the test handler saw the principal it was supposed to. That should work fine, and that should be the behavior you care about.