# C# .net 4.5 - Asynchronous task & socket

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets

Next step in my discovery of .net.

At the beginning I was using threads.  After a discussion on another question (thanks ledbutter) I'm now using tasks.

So I have :

```
   private async void Tasks_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task myTask = doSomething();
        await Task.WhenAll(myTask);
        Console.WriteLine("....");
    }
    private async Task doSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting doSomething3");
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("Finishing doSomething3");
    }
```

Now in my doSomething I want to use sockets to listen to a specified port.
In my version with threads, I was doing :

```
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
sock.Bind(iep);
EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)iep;
Console.WriteLine("Ready to receive...");
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);
string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
Console.WriteLine("received: {0}  from: {1}", stringData, ep.ToString());
sock.Close();
```

But if put put this code in the doSomething method, the RreceiveForm block the ui thread and all other tasks.

How can I do ?

Comment: Please show the full new code of the doSomething method.

Comment: Here's an example of a TCP server which is thread-agnostic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21018042/1768303

Comment: The full code is : you replace await Task.Delay(3000); by all the code in the next block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your network code does not await anything, so it does not run asynchronously. Either use the asynchronous operations of the Socket class, e.g. `await sock.ReceiveFromAsync(...);`, or run the code as a Task, e.g. `await Task.Run(()=>{/*your code here*/});`

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I tried with await Task.Run(()=>{waitPacket()}); and public void waitPacket(){ ... }.  It's working.  But in the Tasks_Button_Click, no matters if I put await Task.WhenAll(myTask); the Console.WriteLine("...."); only happens when the waitPacket is finished.  I'd like to try the other method (ReceiveFromAsync) if I found examples.

Comment: Note the `Task.Run(` version is just your thread version "pretttyfied" it still has the same problems with scaling. See the example that was linked to in your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013751/what-is-the-async-await-equivalent-of-a-threadpool-server/21018042#21018042

Comment: Ok,so using threads and Task.Run it is the same.  The 'look' is different but the result is the same.  It is right ?  And indeed using this solution, it's impossible to update ui within the task.  So what would be the solution ?

Comment: Don't find examples with ReceiveFromAsync.