# Multiple access to List<Socket>

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, sockets

I develop the server in C# and have a question:

Let's say I have the `List <Socket>`, it have 20 objects, from the first object (socket) comes a message that I must:

- duplicate to all objects in the worksheet

or

- duplicate to one particular object

Everything works correctly, if it is currently work one thread with `List <Socket>`.
But if to `List <Socket>` suddenly turn 20 threads simultaneously (message arrived from everyone), which not only pass on the List and send a message, but also on the basis of the contents of the messages can close the socket and remove it from the List, then I do not know how to create atomic access and not lose productivity.

```
String targetIp, msg;

lock(socketListMutex)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < listSocket.Count; ++i)
    {
        if(listSocket.elementAt(i).targetIp == targetIp)
        {
            listSocket.sendTo(msg);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

What can happen:

- One of the 20 falls off.
- The list is removed fallen off the socket, and it was in the beginning. As a consequence - the list has shifted to the left.
- At this time all of the sent message and stood in the middle of the cycle. As a result - missed one socket.

Comment: Id say use a mutex, but the code sample you provided has one. Is the code sample what you want to do or what you have done or what is working or what isn't working?

Comment: That's what I did. Need to modify something (Edit 1)

Comment: @dima Your loop won't be running at the moment of removing of list's element as long as you use `lock` properly throughout your code - that's what's it for. Your scenario will never happen then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is based on my understanding of your question, while I'm not quite sure I understood it correctly.

A solution could be as simple as making a copy of the list of sockets, before processing it:

```
Socket[] sockets;
lock (socketListMutex) 
    sockets = listSocket.ToArray();

foreach (socket in sockets)
{
    // check the state of each socket object
    // and send a message if needed
}
```

Your requirements don't mention the situation when a new message arrive (possibly on a different socket) before the previous one has been fully processed. In this case, some additional logic would be required to preserve the order of the messages, like queuing.

On a side note, I don't think you need additional threads. Use asynchronous APIs instead:

```
foreach (socket in sockets)
{
    // send a message to each socket
    await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
        (asyncCallback, state) =>
            socket.BeginSend(buffer, offset, size, socketFlags, asyncCallback, state),
        (asyncResult) =>
            request.EndSend(asyncResult));
}
```

More on asynchronous socket operations:

[Awaiting Socket Operations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx).

Some thoughts about the threading model of a TCP server app:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21018042/1768303