# Does async/await affects tcp server performance?

Tags: c#, tcp, async-await

I am creating a Tcp server in C# 5.0 and I am using the await keyword when calling `tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync` and `networkStream.ReadAsync`

However when I check the CPU usage of my server with Process Explorer I have the following results:

Tcp Sync version:  **10% CPU usage**

Tcp Async Version: **30% CPU usage** Half of the usage is kernel usage.

Moreover, I measured how many time I received data by adding a counter inside the while look of the network stream, and the async version loops 120,000 times while the sync version loops 2,500,000 times.

In term of message received/second the async version is 15% slower than the sync version when receiving messages from 3 different clients.

**Why does the Async Version use a lot more CPU than the Sync version?**

Is this because of the async/await keyword ?

**Is this normal that an Async Tcp server is slower than its sync counterpart?**

***EDIT: Here is an example of the async tcp server code***

```
public class AsyncTcpListener : ITcpListener
{ 
    private readonly ServerEndpoint _serverEndPoint;  // Custom class to store IpAddress and Port

    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

    private readonly List<AsyncTcpClientConnection> _tcpClientConnections = new List<AsyncTcpClientConnection>(); 

    private TcpListener _tcpListener;

    public AsyncTcpMetricListener()
    {
        _serverEndPoint = GetServerEndpoint();  
    }

    public async void Start()
    {
        IsRunning = true;

        RunTcpListener();
    }

    private void MessageArrived(byte[] buffer)
    { 
        // Deserialize
    }

    private void RunTcpListener(){
       _tcpListener = null;
        try
        {
            _tcpListener = new TcpListener(_serverEndPoint.IpAddress, _serverEndPoint.Port);
            _tcpListener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                var tcpClient = await _tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                var asyncTcpClientConnection = new AsyncTcpClientConnection(tcpClient,  MessageArrived);
                _tcpClientConnections.Add(asyncTcpClientConnection);
            }
        } 
        finally
        {
            if (_tcpListener != null)
                _tcpListener.Stop();

            IsRunning = false;
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        IsRunning = false; 
        _tcpListener.Stop();
        _tcpClientConnections.ForEach(c => c.Close());
    }
}
```

For each new client we create a new AsyncTcpConnection

```
public class AsyncTcpClientConnection
{ 
    private readonly Action<byte[]> _messageArrived;
    private readonly TcpClient _tcpClient; 

    public AsyncTcpClientConnection(TcpClient tcpClient, Action<byte[]> messageArrived)
    {
        _messageArrived = messageArrived;
        _tcpClient = tcpClient; 
        ReceiveDataFromClientAsync(_tcpClient); 
    }

    private async void ReceiveDataFromClientAsync(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        var readBuffer = new byte[2048];
        // PacketProtocol class comes from http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html
        var packetProtocol = new PacketProtocol(2048);  
        packetProtocol.MessageArrived += _messageArrived;

        try
        {
            using (tcpClient)
            using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            {
                int readSize;
                while ((readSize = await networkStream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
                {
                    packetProtocol.DataReceived(readBuffer, readSize); 
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log
        } 
    } 

    public void Close()
    {
        _tcpClient.Close();
    }
}
```

***EDIT2: Synchronous server***

```
 public class TcpListener : ITcpListener
{  
    private readonly ObserverEndpoint _serverEndPoint; 
    private readonly List<TcpClientConnection> _tcpClientConnections = new List<TcpClientConnection>();

    private Thread _listeningThread;
    private TcpListener _tcpListener;
    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

    public TcpMetricListener()
    {
        _serverEndPoint = GetServerEndpoint();   

    }


    public void Start()
    {
        IsRunning = true;
        _listeningThread = BackgroundThread.Start(RunTcpListener);  
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        IsRunning = false;

        _tcpListener.Stop();
        _listeningThread.Join();
        _tcpClientConnections.ForEach(c => c.Close());
    }

    private void MessageArrived(byte[] buffer)
    {
        // Deserialize
    }

    private void RunTcpListener()
    {
        _tcpListener = null;
        try
        {
            _tcpListener = new TcpListener(_serverEndPoint.IpAddress, _serverEndPoint.Port);
            _tcpListener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                var tcpClient = _tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                _tcpClientConnections.Add(new TcpClientConnection(tcpClient, MessageArrived));
            }
        } 
        finally
        {
            if (_tcpListener != null)
                _tcpListener.Stop();

            IsRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And the connection

```
public class TcpClientConnection
{ 
    private readonly Action<byte[]> _messageArrived;
    private readonly TcpClient _tcpClient;
    private readonly Task _task; 
    public TcpClientConnection(TcpClient tcpClient,   Action<byte[]> messageArrived)
    {
        _messageArrived = messageArrived;
        _tcpClient = tcpClient; 
        _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReceiveDataFromClient(_tcpClient), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

    }

    private void ReceiveDataFromClient(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        var readBuffer = new byte[2048];
        var packetProtocol = new PacketProtocol(2048);
        packetProtocol.MessageArrived += _messageArrived;


            using (tcpClient)
            using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            {
                int readSize;
                while ((readSize = networkStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    packetProtocol.DataReceived(readBuffer, readSize); 
                }
            } 
    }


    public void Close()
    {
        _tcpClient.Close();
        _task.Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not awating a call to `ReceiveDataFromClientAsync` inside `AsyncTcpClientConnection`. While not related to performance, it is still a bug.

Comment: I can't await `ReceiveDataFromClientAsync` because the program would wait forever and never listen for another tcp client

Comment: See if this helps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605876.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have also issues with an `async` and these are my findings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22222578/307976

Also, I have an asynchronous TCP server/client using `async` example [here](https://github.com/vtortola/AynchronousTCPListener) that scales well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insight. Your implementation is nice. I like the way you handle a clean close of the server. I refactored my listener using some of the code of your server implementation. However performance are still the same, with the same CPU spikes.

Comment: Have you checked that those CPU spikes are not the GC cleaning garbage? Open the performance collector add the "% of time in GC" counter for your server application instance and check if the spikes align with the spikes you are mentioning. I have the feeling that asynchronous code make life difficult for the GC.

Comment: Less than 1% time in GC for my algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following implementation of `ReceiveInt32Async` and `ReceiveDataAsync` for receiving your length-prefixed messages directly, instead of using `tcpClient.GetStream` and `networkStream.ReadAsync`:

```
public static class SocketsExt
{
    static public async Task<Int32> ReceiveInt32Async(
        this TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        var data = new byte[sizeof(Int32)];
        await tcpClient.ReceiveDataAsync(data).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
    }

    static public Task ReceiveDataAsync(
        this TcpClient tcpClient,
        byte[] buffer)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(
            (asyncCallback, state) =>
                tcpClient.Client.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 
                    SocketFlags.None, asyncCallback, state),
            (asyncResult) =>
                tcpClient.Client.EndReceive(asyncResult), 
            null);
    }
}
```

See if this gives any improvements. On a side note, I also suggest making `ReceiveDataFromClientAsync` an `async Task` method and storing the `Task` it returns inside `AsyncTcpClientConnection` (for status and error tracking).

Comment: I tried your implementation and it causes two problems: 1) it is a lot slower (4k messages/sec instead of 220k messages/sec). 2) it does not takes into account the fact we can receive incomplete packets in TCP. It is however very elegant code.

Comment: @alexandrekow, 1) I thought'd be worth trying :), 2) I thought that's what the message length prefix was for. In theory, an async receive operation like this is *not* complete until *all* requested data has been received; i.e., for `Int32` it completes as soon as 4 bytes has been received, for `buff[]` - `buff.Length` bytes.

Comment: @alexandrekow, one more step would be to try this with an increased [`Socket.ReceiveBufferSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivebuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx)