# What's the correct way to run multiple parallel tasks in an asp.net process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

I think I'm not understanding something. I had thought that `Task.Yield()` forced a new thread/context to be started for a task but upon [re-reading this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22645114/5056) it seems that it merely forces the method to be async. It will still be on the same context.

What's the correct way - in an asp.net process - to create and run multiple tasks in parallel without causing deadlock?

In other words, suppose I have the following method:

```
async Task createFileFromLongRunningComputation(int input) { 
    //many levels of async code
}
```

And when a certain POST route is hit, I want to simultaneously launch the above methods 3 times, **return immediately**, but log when all three are done.

I think I need to put something like this into my action

```
public IHttpAction Post() {
   Task.WhenAll(
       createFileFromLongRunningComputation(1),
       createFileFromLongRunningComputation(2),
       createFileFromLongRunningComputation(3)
   ).ContinueWith((Task t) =>
      logger.Log("Computation completed")
   ).ConfigureAwait(false);
   return Ok();
```

}

What needs to go into `createFileFromLongRunningComputation`? I had thought `Task.Yield` was correct but it apparently is not.

Comment: Calling `ConfigureAwait` is pointless if you never actually `await` the `Task`.

Comment: Thanks @Servy I kind of knew that but it slipped my mind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **correct** way to offload concurrent work to different threads is to use `Task.Run` as rossipedia suggested.

The best solutions for background processing in **ASP.Net** (where your `AppDomain` can be recycled/shut down automatically together with all your tasks) are in [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) and [Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)'s blogs (e.g. HangFire)

However, you *could* utilize `Task.Yield` together with `ConfigureAwait(false)` to achieve the same.

All `Task.Yield` does is return an awaiter that makes sure the rest of the method doesn't proceed synchronously (by having `IsCompleted` return `false` and `OnCompleted` execute the `Action` parameter immediately). `ConfigureAwait(false)` disregards the `SynchronizationContext` and so forces the rest of the method to execute on a `ThreadPool` thread.

If you use both together you can make sure an `async` method returns a task immediately which will execute on a `ThreadPool` thread (like `Task.Run`):

```
async Task CreateFileFromLongRunningComputation(int input)
{
    await Task.Yield().ConfigureAwait(false);
    // executed on a ThreadPool thread
}
```

---

Edit:
George Mauer pointed out that since `Task.Yield` returns `YieldAwaitable` you can't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` which is a method on the `Task` class.

You can achieve something similar by using `Task.Delay` with a very short timeout, so it wouldn't be synchronous but you wouldn't waste much time:

```
async Task CreateFileFromLongRunningComputation(int input)
{
    await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false);
    // executed on a ThreadPool thread
}
```

A better option would be to create a `YieldAwaitable` that simply disregards the `SynchronizationContext` the same as using `ConfigureAwait(false)` does:

```
async Task CreateFileFromLongRunningComputation(int input)
{
    await new NoContextYieldAwaitable();
    // executed on a ThreadPool thread
}

public struct NoContextYieldAwaitable
{
    public NoContextYieldAwaiter GetAwaiter() { return new NoContextYieldAwaiter(); }
    public struct NoContextYieldAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
    {
        public bool IsCompleted { get { return false; } }
        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            var scheduler = TaskScheduler.Current;
            if (scheduler == TaskScheduler.Default)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(RunAction, continuation);
            }
            else
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(continuation, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness, scheduler);
            }
        }

        public void GetResult() { }
        private static void RunAction(object state) { ((Action)state)(); }
    }
}
```

---

<sup>This isn't a recommendation, it's an answer to your Task.Yield questions.</sup>

Comment: This is the correct answer to the _actual question_. My answer has more discussion points about whether or not the OPs approach is a good one.

Comment: @rossipedia indeed. And I want to reiterate, this isn't how real code should look like.

Comment: Oy vey, now gotta figure out if I can convince infra to deploy 4.5.2

Comment: `Task.Yield()` does not return a Task and therefore there is no `ConfigureAwait` function. So the not-recommended approach doesn't work.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer you're right, I haven't thought about. I added a really interesting solution to the answer.

Comment: Interesting, any particular reason why `NoContextYieldAwaiter` is a struct?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Yes. It's a struct because `YieldAwaiter` (and `TaskAwaiter` are structs). And they are structs for optimization reasons, mainly to reduce heap allocations.

Answer (score 4):

([l3arnon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27988090/115049) is the correct one. This answer is more of a discussion on whether the approach posed by the OP is a good one.)

You don't need anything special, really. The `createFileFromLongRunningComputation` method doesn't need anything special, just make sure you are `await`ing some async method in it and the `ConfigureAwait(false)` *should* avoid the deadlock, assuming you're not doing anything out of the ordinary (probably just file I/O, given the method name).

**Caveat**:

This is risky. ASP.net will most likely pull the rug out from under you in this situation if the tasks take too long to finish.

As one of the commenters pointed out, there are better ways of accomplishing this. One of them is [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem(v=vs.110).aspx) (which is only available in .NET 4.5.2 and up).

If the long running computation takes a significantly long time to complete, you're probably better off keeping it out of ASP.net entirely. In that situation, a better method would be to use some sort of message queue, and a service that processes those messages outside of IIS/ASP.net.

Comment: But there's certain situations in asp.net where that will cause a deadlock when await is used. Also, according to the linked answer, this might still run synchronously.

Comment: As long as he's got that `ConfigureAwait(false)`, and doesn't attempt to access the `HttpContext` from the request, he _should_ be ok.

Comment: @rossipedia are you aware that you're not actually waiting for these tasks to complete?

Comment: @l3arnon notice that I do not want to wait for the tasks to complete, I want to return immediately. What I'm wary about this is what about the comment that `Task.Run` *might* run synchronously

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Then why is the title 'await multiple tasks". Also, this is very risky. If you want to have background processing in asp.net there are better ways.

Comment: @l3arnon Yup. OP stated he wants to return immediately, ie: not wait for those tasks to finish. They will finish on a ThreadPool thread. I've used the technique successfully quite a few times.

Comment: Given that, you make a good point. There are definitely better ways.

Comment: Thanks @l3arnon I fixed up the title. What do you mean by better ways to run background tasks?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer all you need is here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: Can I ask why you've wrapped the `createFileFromLongRunningComputation` calls in `Task.Run`? I've just tried it without and it seems to behave the same, but will freely admit I don't 100% know what I'm doing.

Comment: Also related - http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html

Comment: @Rawling the actual use case is the typical REST pattern where you POST a resource that is going to kick off some background computation, get back an id, and later are able to GET aspects of that resource by id. `POST /CreateReport` returns back id 12345 and kicks off processing. Later you can do `GET /Report/12345?pageStart=5&pageEnd=50`

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: You really should not be doing this in ASP.NET, then. You should have a persistent queue with an independent backend worker process.

Comment: He already has asynchronous tasks.  There is no reason to wrap them in calls to `Run`; it's just wasting time scheduling a task in the thread pool to *start* an asynchronous operation.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary I imagine your Fire And Forget article covers this? I'm wary to introduce a ton of new infrastructure for just this one feature.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: Yes. You can always `await` them before returning to the caller if you want to keep it in ASP.NET. If you want to return "early", then you'll need an appropriate architecture to support that requirement.

Comment: @Servy You're absolutely right. It's early here, I need more coffee.