# Why does this Task.Run lambda run synchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I am trying to make some code run multithreaded using `SemaphoreSlim` and `Task.Run()`.

Here is the snippet:

```
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(50, 50);
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    semaphore.Wait();

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        item.Property = DoTheThing(item.AnotherValue).Result;
        db.SaveChanges();
        semaphore.Release();
    });
}
```

What I expected to happen is that 50 tasks would be queued up and then `semaphore.Wait()` would kick in and hold the foreach loop until some tasks complete and `semaphore.Release()` frees up the threads so more can be queued.

What actually happens is the code runs synchronously one after the other. What am I missing here?  I thought `Task.Run()` launched the lambda code on a new thread?

Comment: `Task.Run()` returns a `Task` object, which you are not waiting on.

Comment: @siride exactly, i am using SemaphoreSlim to control how many tasks get started.  I am using this pattern with non-lambda expression and it works but with lambda expression it doesn't work for some reason and only single thread runs

Comment: @Guerrilla: I'm still new to this, but I think then what you may want is to create an array of tasks and then use `Task.WhenAll()` on that array. You can do the semaphore wait within the lambda.

Comment: ... or `Task.WhenAny()`, depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Lol at people voting to close because this is not related to programming.  I managed to figure it out, the documentation doesnt show this on example but it needs to be called like `Task.Run( async () => { lambda } );`

Comment: I did not vote to close! I think it's a legitimate question. You should post that as an answer. I would also try working in the `WhenAll()` business.

Comment: *Lol at people voting to close because this is not related to programming*: No one did that. Yes, there are some close votes, but not for that reason.

Comment: @sstan "This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined" 2 x votes.

Comment: @Guerilla: Ah, I see. That's misleading. If you drill down deeper into the subcategories, you'll see that the actual reason is not that at all.

Comment: @sstan ahh didnt realise there was sub-cats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at here: [When would I use Task.Yield()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645024/when-would-i-use-task-yield)

Essentially `Task.Run()` does not guarantee that the code in it runs asynchronously. If you want to ensure that you have to do this:

```
Task.Run(async ()
{
    await Task.Yield();
    ...
});
```

Comment: "does not guarantee that the code in it runs asynchronously" That doesn't sound right. From the docs on Task.Run: "Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool and returns a Task object that represents that work."