# What does an await Task.Yield do when in a Xamarin Forms OnAppearing?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My OnAppearing code looks like this. I don't understand what this is added for:

```
`await Task.Yield()`
```

Can someone explain what this does?

```
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        Utils.SetState(Settings.mode.Text(), vm.Mode);
        vm.CfsLabel = Settings.cfs.Text();

        SetMode(Settings.mode.Text());
        Subscribe();
        ContentPageStack.IsVisible = true;
        if (!openedOnce)
        {
            // can someone explain what the following line
            // is doing here in the code. What's the Task
            // that it refers to and what does Yield do? 
            await Task.Yield();

            await scroll.ScrollToAsync(0, 0, false);
            openedOnce = true;
        }
        if (App.devIsUser)
            Analytics.TrackEvent(VersionTracking.CurrentVersion + " - On Appearing - home page");
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When would I use Task.Yield()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645024/when-would-i-use-task-yield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In this particular case,* `await Task.Yield` does nothing useful. It is probably a misguided attempt to process Win32 messages like `WM_PAINT`. I.e., a "poor man's `DoEvents`".

`await Task.Yield` is used to [force asynchrony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645024/when-would-i-use-task-yield). It's a way of forcing `await` to behave asynchronously, returning to the caller. It also immediately queues the remainder of the method to run.

The reason this doesn't work as a "poor man's `DoEvents`" is because the Win32 message queue is prioritized. So this is what the `await Task.Yield` actually does in this particular instance:

- Queues the continuation of the `async` method to the current context (the UI `SynchronizationContext`), which places the continuation into the Win32 message queue.
- Returns from the `async` method. Since this is an event handler, this returns to the Win32 message processing loop.
- The Win32 message process loop pulls the next message from its queue. Since the queue is prioritized, it will always skip over regular Win32 messages and take the continuation message.
- The loop processes the message, which runs the continuation of the `async` method, so the event handler resumes executing right where it left off.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Microsoft docs give you a clear picture of what it does, When you read about [Task.Yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield?view=netframework-4.8) its says:

> Creates an awaitable task that asynchronously yields back to the current context when awaited.
>
> Returns
>   **YieldAwaitable**
>
> A context that, when awaited, will asynchronously transition back into the current context at the time of the `await`. If the current SynchronizationContext is non-null, it is treated as the current context. Otherwise, the task scheduler that is associated with the currently executing task is treated as the current context.

What this basically means is when you use `await Task.Yield` in an async method it will force the method to complete asynchronously. And if there is a [Synchronization Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.8) available it will execute the remainder of the method's execution back to that context.

**Note:** The synchronization context that is present on a UI thread in most UI environments will often prioritize work posted to the context higher than input and rendering work. For this reason, do not rely on await Task.Yield(); to keep a UI responsive.