# What is the difference between starting a worker via Task.Run and just calling an async method (don't await) with await Task.Yield inside?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await

Consider a service which needs to do different kinds of work simultaneously, e.g. process messages from a message queue or queues and post some changing info to some database once per a period of time.

I am used to create these 'workers' this way:

```
public void Start()
{
    _queueProcessingTask = Task.Run(async () => await ProcessMessages(_cts.Token), _cts.Token);
    _dataPostingTask = Task.Run(async () => await PostToDatabase(_cts.Token), _cts.Token);
}
```

So, we have a class, that keeps track of the two tasks and has a means of cancelling them. `ProcessMessages` and `PostToDatabase` are just private async Task-returning methods, containing infinite loops with some logic.

We capture a thread pool thread to run our method on, and the thread is going to be returned to the pool, when it reaches the first `await` inside the logic. After this, thread pool threads will be running continuations throughout the logic.

There is also one way of starting these workers:

```
public void Start()
{
    _queueProcessingTask = ProcessMessages(_cts.Token);
    _dataPostingTask = PostToDatabase(_cts.Token);
}

private async Task ProcesMessages(CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    // here goes our endless while loop with logic...
}

private async Task PostToDatabase(CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    // here goes our endless while loop with logic...
}
```

In this example we don't call `Task.Run`, we just call the methods, synchronously wait to get the awaitable out of the Task.Yield() and are given control back immediately. Then, a thread pool thread will be captured to run the continuations in our method logic like in the first case.

Both examples work identically concerning the observable behavior.

My questions are:

1. Is there some overhead of capturing a separate thread using Task.Run, as opposed to doing a bare call of a method with Task.Yield inside?
2. Are my assumptions about the scenarios in both cases correct? Is there anything I should think of additionally?
3. What is the best way to have such workers in your service, and are there any general guidelines for this?

Comment: "a thread pool thread will be captured to run the continuations in our method logic like in the first case." - your code doesn't actually _guarantee_ that. Your code is using `Task`'s defaults in whatever the current platform is.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `await Task.Yield()`? Is it to [offload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69880987/when-is-it-asynchronous-and-when-is-synchronous/69881887#69881887) the rest of the asynchronous method on the `ThreadPool`?