# How does Task.Yield work under the hood in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, blazor, webassembly

How does `Task.Yield` work under the hood in [Mono/WASM runtime](https://github.com/mono/mono) (which is used by Blazor WebAssembly)?

To clarify, I believe I have a good understanding of [how `Task.Yield` works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22652690/1768303) in .NET Framework and .NET Core. [Mono implementation](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/bdd772531d379b4e78593587d15113c37edd4a64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/YieldAwaitable.cs) doesn't look much different, in a nutshell, it comes down to this:

```cs
static Task Yield() 
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => tcs.TrySetResult(true));
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Surprisingly, this works in Blazor WebAssembly, too ([try it online](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/GFllwyEX012Xb9oz39)):

```razor
<label>Tick Count: @tickCount</label><br>

@code 
{
    int tickCount = System.Environment.TickCount;

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender) CountAsync();
    }

    static Task Yield() 
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => tcs.TrySetResult(true));
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    async void CountAsync() 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) 
        {
            await Yield();
            tickCount = System.Environment.TickCount;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Naturally, it all happens on the same event loop thread in the browser, so I wonder how it works on the lower level.

I suspect, it might be utilizing something like [Emscripten's Asyncify](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/asyncify.html#asyncify), but eventually, does it use some sort of Web Platform API to schedule a continuation callback? And if so, which one exactly (like [`queueMicrotask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/queueMicrotask), [`setTimout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout), [`Promise.resove().then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve), etc)?

---

**Updated**, I've just discovered that `Thread.Sleep` is implemented as well and it actually [blocks the event loop thread](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/cvFPmokM49CAxIVn28)

Curious about how that works on the WebAssembly level, too. With JavaScript, I can only think of a busy loop to simulate `Thread.Sleep` (as [`Atomics.wait`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics/wait) is only available from web worker threads).

Comment: If I understand correctly the dotnet runtime is compiled to webassembly. I'm guessing that it has more to do with webassembly supporting multi threading: https://web.dev/webassembly-threads/

Comment: @mcbr thanks for the link! It led me to [an answer about `Thread.Sleep`](https://web.dev/asyncify/#:~:text=its%20default%20implementation%20of%20%22sleep%22), last but not least.

Comment: As far as I know - blazor doesn't support web assembly multithreading yet (in reply to first comment)

Comment: @Evk, true AFAIK as well. Even if it used pthreads, imagine how expensive it'd be to do something like `await Task.Yield()`, if it worked in the same way as it does in .NET 6.x. They'd probably have to introduce `SynchonizationContext` for the main thread to mitigate that (currently, `SynchonizationContext.Current` is `null` in Blazor/WASM).

Comment: @BrunoGarcia points out: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/12453#issuecomment-744983773

Comment: Short answer: `YieldAwaitable Task.Yield() { return default; }`. And because `SyncContext.Current == null` the question is actually about how the ThreadPool works on WebAssembly.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, yep that's essentially my question: *... does it use some sort of Web Platform API to schedule a continuation callback? And if so, which one exactly (like `queueMicrotask`, `setTimout`, `Promise.resove().then`, etc)?*

Comment: I have a similar curiosity, but regarding how the Garbage Collector is implemented. Does it run as interleaved, high-level tasks in the thread pool or is it triggered as part of the new() operator execution?  Does it have a stop-the-world phase that may block the event-loop thread for a considerable time every now and then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It’s `setTimeout`.  There is considerable indirection between that and `QueueUserWorkItem`, but this is where it bottoms out.

Most of the WebAssembly-specific machinery can be seen in [PR 38029](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/38029/files).  The WebAssembly implementation of `RequestWorkerThread` calls a private method named `QueueCallback`, which is implemented in C code as `mono_wasm_queue_tp_cb`.  This in invokes [`mono_threads_schedule_background_job`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ce4eb48eb8950e3a1454149af14318494a1ca95e/src/mono/mono/utils/mono-threads-wasm.c#L313-L322), which in turn calls [`schedule_background_exec`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/68c0055ff08da5c9fe5bd8fb2b3993a9ceb03828/src/mono/wasm/runtime/scheduling.ts#L59-L65), which is implemented in TypeScript as:

```typescript
export function schedule_background_exec(): void {
    ++pump_count;
    if (typeof globalThis.setTimeout === "function") {
        globalThis.setTimeout(pump_message, 0);
    }
}
```

The `setTimeout` callback eventually reaches `ThreadPool.Callback`, which invokes `ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch`.

The rest of it is not specific to Blazor at all, and can be studied by reading the source code of the [`ThreadPoolWorkQueue`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c158cb2fe35c17d8fb7de802c1ffba74c2b936b2/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/ThreadPoolWorkQueue.cs) class.  In short, `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` enqueues the callback in a `ThreadPoolQueue`.  Enqueueing calls `EnsureThreadRequested`, which delegates to `RequestWorkerThread`, implemented as above.  `ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch` causes some number of asynchronous tasks to be dequeued and executed; among them, the callback passed to `QueueUserWorkItem` should eventually appear.

Comment: A great answer, tks! But geven it's `setTimeout`, could you explain a huge discrepancy I'm seeing when timing a loop of `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 0))` with JS interop vs a loop of `await Task.Yield`? Is there a flaw in the test? https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/QlFFQLPF08dkYRbm30

Comment: `queueMicrotask` (as opposed to `setTimeout`) produces a much closer result: https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/QFbFGVFP10NWGSam57

Comment: I am unable to open any of the REPL links, so I cannot tell what you mean. But if you study the source code of `ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch`, you will notice there is some sophisticated scheduling involved as well, and one `setTimeout` may serve multiple queued .NET asynchronous tasks, which I would expect to be faster than having each `setTimeout` dispatch a single callback.

Comment: Odd repl links don't work. If you'd still like to try it, here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/noseratio/73f6cd2fb328387ace2a7761f0b0dadc. It's literrally 8000ms vs 20ms. Then just replace `setTimeout` with `queueMicrotask`, and it's about the same 20ms.

Comment: Seems like it: `setTimeout` makes the browser process the event loop in between callbacks, but the .NET runtime can dispatch multiple asynchronous tasks in a single `setTimeout` callback (dequeuing them almost immediately after they are queued), thus avoiding the overhead of yielding to the event loop. (Also, browsers may perform throttling on `setTimeout` calls, which this batching avoids.) This produces an effect roughly equivalent to `queueMicrotask`. Although the timings you get are probably not very accurate, thanks to Spectre mitigations.