# C#5.0 asynchronous TCP/IP server with await & async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have written following Tcp Server applictaion. The problem is it is not executing individual clients in parallel. That is if one client is connected, the server doesn't accept connections to other clients. Please help me fix the code:

```
void Run()
{
    tcpListener.Start();           

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");

        try
        { 
            var client = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            await Accept(client);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

private async Task Accept(TcpClient client)
{
    //get client information 
    string clientEndPoint = GetClientIPAddress(client);            
    Console.WriteLine("Client connected at " + clientEndPoint);
    log.Info("Client connected at " + clientEndPoint);

    await Task.Yield (); 

    try 
    {              
        using (client) 
            using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream ()) 
            { 
                byte[] dataReceived = new byte [50];                  
                while (await stream.ReadAsync(dataReceived, 0, dataReceived.Length) != 0) //read input stream                
                {                    
                    //process data here                        
                    await ProcessData(dataReceived);                      
                }                   
            }
    } //end try
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);                
        if (client.Connected)
            client.Close();
    }
} //end Accept(TcpClient client)
```

Comment: Are you attempting to connect to the same port multiple times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
await Accept(client);
```

You're awaiting the result of `Accept`, so you're unable to accept new connections (as you're not executing `AcceptTcpClientAsync` while `Accept` is "in-flight").

Here is an example of how it can be done properly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21018042/1768303.

Comment: You should change it to `async void Accept(client) {...}` and just call it normally without the `await` keyword in the Run method.

Comment: @Laith, I'm not a big fan of `async void` fire-and-forget approach. I prefer to keep track of the pending tasks, as done in the linked [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21018042/1768303).

Comment: you're right. If you want to keep track of all the running tasks, you'd want to keep a reference to them somehow. You're approach is better :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, taking the await away from Accept call and changing Accept return from Task to void did solve the problem.

Comment: actually based on your comments i added task back to Accept and calling it in this way: var task = Accept(client)

Comment: @AM0, the idea of using a `Task` without `await` rather than `async void` there is to facilitate the error handling and keep track of the pending connections (in `List<Task>`).