# Security, Thread.CurrentPrincipal, and ConfigureAwait(false)

Tags: async-await, claims-based-identity, synchronizationcontext, executioncontext, current-principal

Would using Thread.CurrentPrincipal's claims in a referenced library that uses ConfigureAwait(false) pose any problems or will the flowing of ExecutionContext's logical call context take care of me there? (my reading and testing so far indicates that it will).

Example WebAPI Controller Action:

```cs
[CustomAuthorizeThatSetsCurrentUsersClaimsToThreadCurrentContextAndHttpContextCurrentUser]
public async Task<Order> Get(int orderId)
{
    return await _orderBusinessLogicLibrary.LoadAsync(orderId); // defaults to .ConfigureAwait(true)
}
```

Example load functions from external, referenced library:

```cs
[ClaimsPrincipalPermission(
    SecurityAction.Demand,
    Operation="Read",
    Resource="Orders")]
[ClaimsPrincipalPermission(
    SecurityAction.Demand,
    Operation="Read",
    Resource="OrderItems")]
public async Task<Order> Load(int orderId)
{
    var order = await _repository.LoadOrderAsync(orderId).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // here's the key line.. assuming this lower-level function is also imposing
    // security constraints in the same way this method does, would
    // Thread.CurrentPrincipal still be correct inside the function below?
    order.Items = await _repository.LoadOrderItemsAsync(orderId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return order;
}
```

Also, the answer can't be "well don't use ConfigureAwait(false) then!".  That can cause other problems such as deadlock ([Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From my tests, it appears that `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` will flow correctly, even if you use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. The following WebAPI code sets the principal and then blocks on an `async` call, forcing *another* thread to resume the `async` method. That other thread does inherit the correct principal.

```cs
private async Task<string> Async()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return "Thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ": " + Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name + "\n";
}

public string Get(int id)
{
    var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(
        new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Bob"),
        }
    ));
    HttpContext.Current.User = user;
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = user;

    var ret = "Thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ": " + Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name + "\n";

    ret += Async().Result;

    return ret;
}
```

When I run this code on a new instance of IISExpress, I get:

```
"Thread 7: Bob\nThread 6: Bob\n"
```

However, I should point out that using `ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid deadlock is not recommended. This is especially true on ASP.NET. If at all possible, use `ConfigureAwait(false)` *and also* use `async` all the way. Note that WebAPI is a fully-`async` stack and you *should* be able to do this.

Comment: Great, I was seeing the same results.  One question for clarification -- your last comment about not using `ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid deadlock is specific to the use of .Result to block on the async method, correct?  So you shouldn't switch from `ConfigureAwait(true)` to `ConfigureAwait(false)` to fix deadlock, you should make the whole stack fully async and would still want `ConfigureAwait(true)` on ASP.NET awaits in order to fully restore HttpContext and so on.

Comment: @MichaelTrotter: The default for `ConfigureAwait` is `true`. So if your `async` method needs the context, it should just not use `ConfigureAwait` at all. If it doesn't need the context, it should use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. I recommend making the whole stack `async` and also using `ConfigureAwait(false)` on any method that doesn't need the context.