# Authorize filter returns 401 although the Thread.CurrentPrinicipal is set

Tags: web, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-authorization

I am running an integration test with HttpClient and HttpServer (In-Memory).

When the test runs a token handler (message handler) is executed where I add this code just for a quick test:

```
protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
        // other code removed for brevity...

    var principal1 = CreatePrincipal(1, "test");
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal1;

    return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}

[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _service.Get(id));
}
```

When I debug into the action`s controller constructor I do base.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated and its set to TRUE.

I would have expected that the action is run because the Thread.CurrentPrincipal is set.

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread.CurrentPrincipal is deprecated in Web API v2. Use HttpRequestMessage.GetRequestContext().Principal (both setting and getting)

Comment: To be correctly its: HttpRequestMessage.GetUserPrincipal()/SetUserPrincipal(user). I will test it tonight at home.

Comment: Using the RequestContext is the general approach - you might have discovered a shortcut - but that doesn't make it more correct ;)

Comment: Ok then I found a convenient method ;-) but I prefer your approach because the conventient stuff needs another assembly added... OK your solution works just tested at office, could not resist :p

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, you should set `HttpContext.User` as well.

Hanselman has a [blog post on the subject](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx), and it's also covered in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16552848/263693). Also note that you may need to force an `async` yield, as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16654386/263693).

Comment: I know I should set HttpContext.Current.User to be correctly ;-) but doing an integration (in-memory) test IIS server is not partaking here thus my HttpContext.Current is always null. Nothing to set here...

Comment: Your first link is about FormsAuth which I not do. I am running .NET 4.5.1 which includes UserTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext.