# Task.Yield - real usages?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, .net-4.5, c#-5.0

I've been reading about `Task.Yield` , And as a Javascript developer I can tell that's it's job is  <strike>*exactly*</strike> the same as `setTimeout(function (){...},0);` in terms of letting the main single thread deal with other stuff aka :

> "don't take all the power , release from time time - so  others would
>   have some too..."

In js it's working particular in long loops. ( *don't make the browser freeze...*)

But I saw this example [here](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=qgq8T4X3erIC&pg=PA574&lpg=PA574&dq=%22the%20task.yield%20method%20creates%22&source=bl&ots=94eP29Nmls&sig=XxEvfX6PVmXhdOdOJC7dlJUGf0I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=t7ZjU5WTJoaxO-f4gXg&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20task.yield%20method%20creates%22&f=false) :

```
public static async Task < int > FindSeriesSum(int i1)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < i1; i++)
    {
        sum += i;
        if (i % 1000 == 0) ( after a bulk , release power to main thread)
            await Task.Yield();
    }

    return sum;
}
```

As a JS programmer I can understand what they did here.

BUT as a C# programmer I ask myself  : why not open  a task for it ?

```
 public static async Task < int > FindSeriesSum(int i1)
    {
         //do something....
         return await MyLongCalculationTask();
         //do something
    }
```

**Question**

With Js I can't open a Task (*<sup>yes i know i can actually with web workers</sup>*) . But with c# **I can**.

**If So** -- why even bother with releasing from time to time while I can release it at all ?

## Edit

**Adding references :**

From [here](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=qgq8T4X3erIC&pg=PA574&lpg=PA574&dq=%22the%20task.yield%20method%20creates%22&source=bl&ots=94eP29Nmls&sig=XxEvfX6PVmXhdOdOJC7dlJUGf0I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=t7ZjU5WTJoaxO-f4gXg&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20task.yield%20method%20creates%22&f=false) : 
[image]

From [here](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=I-dHxFjfbi8C&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=%22task.yield%28%29%22%20%20books&source=bl&ots=QwX60qDOeN&sig=6YlwxL1aX_OuYzpU8ENoYUM8TR0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=O5lkU5zKBumM7Qbqx4BY&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22task.yield%28%29%22%20%20books&f=false) (another ebook):

[image]

Comment: That's a poor example, because `Task.Yield` won't keep the UI responsive. Also, `async` and `await` do not free up the UI thread; if you have a long calculation, you'll need to use `Task.Run`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Considering a multi threaded app (ASP.NET or similar) where a task is already being executed on the thread pool and the thread pool is a valuable resource: If a long running CPU intensive task would call `await Task.Yield()` every second then other short running tasks should get a chance without pending in the queue for a long time. Wouldn't this be fair behavior?

Comment: @springy76: The preemptive thread switching built into every modern OS combined with the self-adjusting thread pool in .NET will work far better than a manual `await Task.Yield()`.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

When you see:

```
await Task.Yield();
```

you can think about it this way:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew( 
    () => {}, 
    CancellationToken.None, 
    TaskCreationOptions.None, 
    SynchronizationContext.Current != null?
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(): 
        TaskScheduler.Current);
```

All this does is makes sure the continuation will happen asynchronously in the future. By *asynchronously* I mean that the execution control will return to the caller of the `async` method, and the continuation callback will *not* happen on the same stack frame.

When exactly and on what thread it will happen completely depends on the caller thread's synchronization context.

**For a UI thread**, the continuation will happen upon some future iteration of the message loop, run by `Application.Run` ([WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run(v=vs.110).aspx)) or `Dispatcher.Run` ([WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.run(v=vs.110).aspx)). Internally, it comes down to the Win32 `PostMessage` API, which post a custom message to the UI thread's message queue. The `await` continuation callback will be called when this message gets pumped and processed. You're completely out of control about when exactly this is going to happen.

Besides, Windows has its own priorities for pumping messages: [INFO: Window Message Priorities](https://web.archive.org/web/20130627005845/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/96006). The most relevant part:

> Under this scheme, prioritization can be considered tri-level. All
> posted messages are higher priority than user input messages because
> they reside in different queues. And all user input messages are
> higher priority than WM_PAINT and WM_TIMER messages.

So, if you use `await Task.Yield()` to yield to the message loop in attempt to keep the UI responsive, you are actually at risk of obstructing the UI thread's message loop. Some pending user input messages, as well as `WM_PAINT` and `WM_TIMER`, have a lower priority than the posted continuation message. Thus, if you do `await Task.Yield()` on a tight loop, you still may block the UI.

This is how it is different from the JavaScript's `setTimer` analogy you mentioned in the question. A `setTimer` callback will be called *after* all user input message have been processed by the browser's message pump.

So, `await Task.Yield()` is not good for doing background work on the UI thread. In fact, you very rarely need to run a background process on the UI thread, but sometimes you do, e.g. editor syntax highlighting, spell checking etc. In this case, use the framework's idle infrastructure.

E.g., with WPF you could do `await Dispatcher.Yield(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle)`:

```
async Task DoUIThreadWorkAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    var i = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        await Dispatcher.Yield(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);

        // do the UI-related work item
        this.TextBlock.Text = "iteration " + i++;
    }
}
```

For WinForms, you could use `Application.Idle` event:

```
// await IdleYield();

public static Task IdleYield()
{
    var idleTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    // subscribe to Application.Idle
    EventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (s, e) =>
    {
        Application.Idle -= handler;
        idleTcs.SetResult(true);
    };
    Application.Idle += handler;
    return idleTcs.Task;
}
```

[It is recommended](https://web.archive.org/web/20151029200959/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/03/20/keeping-apps-fast-and-fluid-with-asynchrony-in-the-windows-runtime.aspx) that you do not exceed 50ms for each iteration of such background operation running on the UI thread.

**For a non-UI thread** with no synchronization context, `await Task.Yield()` just switches the continuation to a random pool thread. There is no guarantee it is going to be a *different* thread from the current thread, it's only guaranteed to be an *asynchronous* continuation. If `ThreadPool` is starving, it may schedule the continuation onto the same thread.

**In ASP.NET**, doing `await Task.Yield()` doesn't make sense at all, except for the workaround mentioned in [@StephenCleary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23436765/1768303). Otherwise, it will only hurt the web app performance with a redundant thread switch.

**So, is `await Task.Yield()` useful?** IMO, not much. It can be used as a shortcut to run the continuation via `SynchronizationContext.Post` or `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, if you really need to impose asynchrony upon a part of your method.

**Regarding the books you quoted**, in my opinion those approaches to using `Task.Yield` are wrong. I explained why they're wrong for a UI thread, above. For a non-UI pool thread, there's simply no *"other tasks in the thread to execute"*, unless you running a custom task pump like [Stephen Toub's `AsyncPump`](https://web.archive.org/web/20151210031057/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx).

**Updated to answer the comment:**

> ... how can it be asynchronouse operation and stay in the same thread
> ?..

As a simple example: WinForms app:

```
async void Form_Load(object s, object e) 
{ 
    await Task.Yield(); 
    MessageBox.Show("Async message!");
}
```

`Form_Load` will return to the caller (the WinFroms framework code which has fired `Load` event), and then the message box will be shown asynchronously, upon some future iteration of the message loop run by `Application.Run()`. The continuation callback is queued with `WinFormsSynchronizationContext.Post`, which internally posts a private Windows message to the UI thread's message loop. The callback will be executed when this message gets pumped, still on the same thread.

In a console app, you can run a similar serializing loop with `AsyncPump` mentioned above.

Comment: Noseration , hi :-) . You said : _"There is no guarantee it is going to be a different thread from the current thread, it's only guaranteed to be an asynchronous continuation"_ . — But if it would stay on the same thread - the operation become synchronous operation. no ? in other words , how can it be asynchronouse operation and stay in the same thread ? asynchrounsey is about continuations - meaning "I will  come back and continue where it stopped". but if it is in the same thread , it is more likely it never left the oprtaion.....no ?

Comment: Hey @RoyiNamir, it's quite possible to continue asynchronously on the same thread, check my update.

Comment: Yes :) , but you wrote the comment in the _non-UI thread_ section , which makes me confusion.....

Comment: @RoyiNamir, you can do that on a non-UI thread too, with the magic of `SynchronizationContext`. Have you looked at [`AsyncPump`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx)? After all, asynchrony doesn't assume multi-threading. It's just something that will deliver a result in the future. Note, even when you deal with `ThreadPool` without any s.context, there's a chance that the continuation will happen on the same thread (e.g., the same pool thread may start and later serve the completion of an async I/O operation, by coincidence).

Comment: I personnally use Task.Yield in only one scenario : protected async virtual Task OverridableMethod()
        {
            await Task.Yield();
        } : here I want a default async implementation that just do nothing, but I can't leave it empty because the method needs to return a Task. Maybe there is a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: @bN_, there is: `protected virtual Task OverridableMethod() { return Task.Task.CompletedTask; }`. Note `async` is not a part of the virtual method signature, so you still can use it when overriding this method in a derived class.

Answer (score 27):

I've only found `Task.Yield` useful in two scenarios:

1. Unit tests, to ensure the code under test works appropriately in the presence of asynchrony.
2. [To work around an obscure ASP.NET issue where identity code *cannot* complete synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16653308/263693).

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not exactly like using `setTimeout` to return control to the UI. In Javascript that would always let the UI update as the `setTimeout` always has a minimum pause of a few milliseconds, and pending UI work has priority over timers, but `await Task.Yield();` doesn't do that.

There is no guarantee that the yield will let any work be done in the main thread, on the contrary the code that called the yield will often be prioritised over UI work.

> "The synchronization context that is present on a UI thread in most UI
>   environments will often prioritize work posted to the context higher
>   than input and rendering work. For this reason, do not rely on await
>   Task.Yield(); to keep a UI responsive."

Ref: [MSDN: Task.Yield Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.yield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: IF not relying on it - so for what it is there ? can you supply REAL example ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It's there for handling multithreading, but not in a way that is reliable for keeping the UI responsive. It makes the method asynchronous, but it doesn't keep it from competing with the main thread for CPU.

Comment: If it may win the main thread priority , then why would i want to use it ? What you are saying is that the code may run sync and not async

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The code runs asyncronously, but you may get the impression that it runs syncronously because of the way that the work is prioritised. Async tasks are more suited for work that is waiting for something to happen, for CPU intensive work you would rather look into the `AsParallel` method.

Answer (score 3):

First of all let me clarify: `Yield` is not exactly the same as `setTimeout(function (){...},0);`. JS is executed in single thread environment, so that is the only way to let other activities to happen. Kind of [cooperative multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking). .net is executed in preemptive multitasking environment with explicit multithreading.

Now back to `Task.Yield`. As I told .net lives in preemptive world, but it is a little more complicated than that. C# `await/async` create interesting mixture of those multitasking mode ruled by state machines. So if you omit `Yield` from your code it will just block the thread and that's it. If you make it a regular task and just call start (or a thread) then it will just do it's stuff in parallel and later block calling thread when `task.Result` is called. What happens when you do `await Task.Yield();` is more complicated. Logically it unblocks the calling code (similar to JS) and execution goes on. What it actually does - it picks another thread and continue execution in it in preemptive environment with calling thread. So it is in calling thread until first `Task.Yield` and then it is on it's own. Subsequent calls to `Task.Yield` apparently don't do anything.

Simple demonstration:

```
class MainClass
{
    //Just to reduce amount of log items
    static HashSet<Tuple<string, int>> cache = new HashSet<Tuple<string, int>>();

    public static void LogThread(string msg, bool clear=false) {
        if (clear)
            cache.Clear ();
        var val = Tuple.Create(msg, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        if (cache.Add (val))
            Console.WriteLine ("{0}\t:{1}", val.Item1, val.Item2);
    }

    public static async Task<int> FindSeriesSum(int i1)
    {
        LogThread ("Task enter");
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < i1; i++)
        {
            sum += i;
            if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                LogThread ("Before yield");
                await Task.Yield ();
                LogThread ("After yield");
            }
        }
        LogThread ("Task done");
        return sum;
    }

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        LogThread ("Before task");
        var task = FindSeriesSum(1000000);
        LogThread ("While task", true);
        Console.WriteLine ("Sum = {0}", task.Result);
        LogThread ("After task");
    }
}
```

Here are results:

```
Before task     :1
Task enter      :1
Before yield    :1
After yield     :5
Before yield    :5
While task      :1
Before yield    :5
After yield     :5
Task done       :5
Sum = 1783293664
After task      :1
```

- Output produced on mono 4.5 on Mac OS X, results may vary on other setups

If you move `Task.Yield` on top of the method it will by async from the beginning and will not block the calling thread.

Conclusion: `Task.Yield` can make possible to mix sync and async code. Some more or less realistic scenario: you have some heavy computational operation and local cache and task `CalcThing`. In this method you check if item is in cache, if yes - return item, if it is not there `Yield` and proceed to calculate it. Actually sample from your book is rather meaningless because nothing useful is achieved there. Their remark regarding GUI interactivity is just bad and incorrect (UI thread will be locked until first call to `Yield`, you should never do that, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.yield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is clear (and correct) on that: "do not rely on await Task.Yield(); to keep a UI responsive".

Comment: The analogy  to JS was in context where GUI apps in c# has a single main thread which runs the UI  -- same as JS single loop. ( and in JS - the the solution is `setTimeout(...,0 )`

Comment: love the demo :)

Answer (score 3):

I think that nobody provided the real answer when to use the Task.Yield.
It is mostly needed if a task uses a never ending loop (or lengthy synchronous job), and can potentially hold a threadpool thread exclusively (not allowing other tasks to use this thread). This can happen if inside the loop the code runs synchronously. the **Task.Yield reschedules** the task to the threadpool queue and the other tasks which waited for the thread can be executed.

**The example:**

```
  CancellationTokenSource cts;
  void Start()
  {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        // run async operation
        var task = Task.Run(() => SomeWork(cts.Token), cts.Token);
        // wait for completion
        // after the completion handle the result/ cancellation/ errors
    }

    async Task<int> SomeWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        int result = 0;

        bool loopAgain = true;
        while (loopAgain)
        {
            // do something ... means a substantial work or a micro batch here - not processing a single byte

            loopAgain = /* check for loop end && */  cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested;
            if (loopAgain) {
                // reschedule  the task to the threadpool and free this thread for other waiting tasks
                await Task.Yield();
            }
        }
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        return result;
    }

    void Cancel()
    {
        // request cancelation
        cts.Cancel();
    }
```

Comment: From the second thought, you could probably use it like that, but it doesn't feel like a good design: queuing a large pile of CPU-bounds tasks to the thread pool (more than it can handle), so they have to yield with `Task.Yield()` to give their peers a chance to execute. There are better options for concurrent CPU-bound scenarios like this, e.g. [`Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel) or [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library).

Comment: @noseratio The possible usage of this pattern  if the code in the loop executes a user defined handler. The code does not know how it behaves - if it is async or synchronous. So as a precaution, in the end of the loop it is better to have a Task.Yield. This is common in message handling buses. When the bus instantiate handlers and process messages. If it has a lot of workers which run in parallel, then it can exaust the threadpool threads. I used it implementing worker coordinator in https://github.com/BBGONE/REBUS-TaskCoordinator

Comment: And one more thing - this can be tested. I have a TaskCoordinator test lab https://github.com/BBGONE/TaskCoordinator which uses this pattern. Without using Task.Yield if you configure to run a lot of tasks in parallel to process messages, then you won't get messages in the console to appear - because all pool threads are busy, and threadpool does not add more - because of the high CPU usage. But when using Task.Yield - the status messages appear in the console. And it processes around 200 000 messages per second, and when there was less overhead (no serialization) -  around 500 000 per second.

Comment: I don't think using Task.Yield to overcome ThreadPool starvation while implementing producer/consumer pattern is a good idea. I suggest you ask a separate question if you want to go into details as to why.

Comment: @noseratio sounds like you're up :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263258/using-task-yield-to-overcome-threadpool-starvation-while-implementing-producer-c

Comment: Not sure why it got down-voted though, it's still an interesting exercise, particularly if you use a custom task scheduler to factor out `ThreadPool`.

Comment: @noseratio I know why it is downvoted. Because people don't test it - how it works in the real world.They are more theoretical than practical. In the real world there are usually larger number of tasks processing than the number of processors on the comp. You have 2 options - use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem directly, or use a loop with async await. Async Await does the same, it queues items to the pool. If the job done on each iteration is more or less substantial, then an additional async - await does not harm. But it increases responsiveness of the system.

Comment: @MaximT, see my comment [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263258/using-task-yield-to-overcome-threadpool-starvation-while-implementing-producer-c#comment93430253_53271612). It'd be great if you can support your vision with a benchmark test like that, and then we could all learn something new. If you take on that, feel free to answer your own question there. Keep in mind though, even if the default `ThreadPool` wins, in real life you can't simply monopolize all of its threads for microtasks like those, because it's a shared resource used by the runtime elsewhere.

Comment: `Task.Yield` does not necessarily cause the continuation in the thread pool (`TaskScheduler.Default`). The continuation is in the ambient `SynchronizationContext` or `TaskScheduler.Current`.

Comment: But most often the TaskScheduler.Current is TaskScheduler.Default and SynchronizationContext  is not set

Comment: Glad to see someone else finally agrees with me on this. I had a rather robust discussion with two folks yesterday on an essentially duplicate question I answered, that was not well received. Kudos in particular to pointing out the *real world* implications.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming the long-running function is one that can run on a background thread. If it isn't, for example because it has UI interaction, then there is no way to prevent blocking the UI while it runs, so the times it runs should be kept short enough not to cause problems for the users.

Another possibility is that you have more long-running functions than you have background threads. In that scenario, it may be better (or it may not matter, it depends) to prevent a few of those functions from taking up all of your threads.

Comment: Your first case is potentially valid, but the second really isn't.  If you have more work, or even workers, than you have threads, then they'll simply need to share that time.  Giving some of that work to the UI thread isn't helpful there.  If you didn't, it would simply mean the UI thread would be idling, thus yielding that time to worker threads.

Comment: @hvd By saying _UI interaction_  - you are talking about a code which can appear (Before || After) the `await`. right ?

Comment: As a (possibly) related thought: it is possible to Join threads in the  server code ... such actions within a Task means that anyone joining this thread doesn't (unknowingly) get blocked for the whole of the rest of this Thread?

Comment: @Servy If you have more long-running functions than you have threads, and all threads are busy, then even short functions don't get a chance to run, and that may give a bad user experience for example if those short-running functions would give the user a status update.

Comment: @hvd You need to have *many* more operations than you have threads, for that to happen.  It is called thread starvation.  In all but the most extreme cases, the thread's scheduler is capable of solving the problem by changing the execution on each thread, allowing each short slices of time to run, rather than running each operation to completion.  On top of *that*, the problem can be solved much more effectively through the use of a thread pool, which can have exactly as many workers as is optional, and queue up the actual work to be done in such a way as to optimize throughput.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I was thinking of methods that use controls (update a label's text), which is something that must happen on the UI thread. That part is not something that's a problem with the method in your question, but it is something that applies to the more general case.

Comment: @Servy You merely need as many running operations as you have background threads, where none of the running tasks gives back control in any reasonable time, do you not?

Comment: @hvd No, that is not something that will cause a problem, because the thread's schedulers are not that poor, and the amount of time that the UI thread would need to be starved out for a human to perceive the lag is quite high.  Other threads don't have the option of holding onto the CPU time forever; in fact, they have almost no control over the matter at all.  It is not a cooperative system, unlike management of the UI thread *from within the UI thread* in which someone can intentionally hog the UI thread for as long as they want, starving everyone else out.

Comment: @Servy That's not at all what I meant. If all background threads are busy running long-running asks, and anything then attempts to start a new task, that new task won't get a chance to run until all of those long-running tasks have finished.

Comment: @hvd That's false.  The thread's CPU scheduler will schedule it for some work before all of those other threads have finished, it just means that every single thread needs to wait a little bit longer for its next time slice for each additional thread the system creates.  You'd have to create hundreds, if not thousands (although this is dependant on the system's hardware), of threads in order to force the UI's time slices to be so infrequent as to make the UI feel unresponsive to a human.

Comment: @Servy Again, that's not at all what I meant. I'm not talking about the UI thread becoming slow. I'm talking about the UI thread starting a new task, which would run on a background thread, do some short work, and once it's finished update the UI. That short work would take a very long time.

Comment: @hvd It will probably take longer, sure, as it needs to share its CPU time with other threads (unless it manages to finish execution in its first time slice).  It won't wait to be scheduled until all other tasks finish though.  It will get some time slices early on.  Because so many CPU operations are short lived, new operations are generally given priority to try to finish quickly.

Comment: @Servy [Here's what I meant.](http://pastebin.com/AqMJhgtS) One button starts a long-running task (waits 10 minutes, pretend it's doing a lot of useful work), one other button starts a task that should finish quickly (waits one second, pretend it's still doing some useful work). Start enough long-running tasks, then start a short-running task, and you'll still be left waiting a *very* long time even for the short-running task to finish. The UI won't be sluggish, but if the short-running task is supposed to do some work before the UI gets updated, that's still a bad user experience.

Comment: @hvd In that case you're using the thread pool, rather than creating new threads.  There are a number of possible resolutions here.  You shouldn't be performing really long running operations in the thread pool (it is designed for lots of reasonably small units of work).  Stick the "long running" task creation option hint on there and it won't use the thread pool, and thus won't cause this problem.  The other option is to break up the one big task into many smaller tasks.  Some operations are well suited for that, some aren't.

Comment: @Servy Third option: let the long-running tasks yield from time to time. Useful if you can't anticipate in advance whether it should be treated as long-running. Hence my answer.

Comment: @hvd Technically that's just one way of accomplishing the second option that I mentioned, it's just a fairly poorly designed way of accomplishing it.  If a task is well suited to being broken up, then break it up.  If it's not, just stick `LongRunning` on it rather than `yield` all over the place.