# What to return from non-async method with Task as the return type?

Tags: c#, async-await

Assume I have a method that is not async but returns a `Task` (because the definition is from an interface intended also for async implementations)

```
public Task DoWorkAsync(Guid id)
{
     // do the work

     return ...;
}
```

What is the best object to return? My current options:

```
return Task.Yield();
return Task.FromResult<object>(null);

// any of the other but cached in a static field and reused.
```

Comment: Side note - if its possible, then introduce separate interface which does not have async operations (ISP principle)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy - the biggest problem in such case is that the caller has to switch between two interfaces depending on the implementation provided (for example, by IoC). I could create a wrapper in between but for it the original question is still important.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can't return `Task.Yield()`, it's not a `Task` but `YieldAwaitable` for use with `await`, and it actually introduces asynchrony (I posted some [more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23441833/1768303)).

I use `Task.FromResult(Type.Missing)` for this purpose. Perhaps, the most efficient, albeit undocumented option is `Task.Delay(0)`, [it returns a static completed task](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#34b191a243434f6a).

Comment: +1. I like `Task.FromResult<object>(null)`, but the .NET team tends to prefer `Task.FromResult(0)`. Neither of those are cached, though.

Comment: I like the undocumented option. I wonder how safe it is to assume that `0x4000` will always mean "do not dispose" and thus create and cache `new Task(false, (TaskCreationOptions)0x4000, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None)` yourself...

Comment: @Knaģis, that probably would be a bad idea, they can change it any time :) Plus, this constructor override is private, you'd need to use reflection.

Comment: @Noseratio - yes, I figured as much... So my current approach will be 
`private static Task _CompletedTask = Task.Delay(0);
public static Task CompletedTask { get { return _CompletedTask; } }` which also enables me to replace the implementation in case in future `Task.Delay(0)` is no longer a no-op.

Comment: @Noseratio, I wonder why you highlighted the fact that your preferred approach returns unique task objects - I currently can't figure out a scenario where in my code the reference equality of tasks would be important...

Comment: @Knaģis, they don't have to be unique and well may be cached, I guess it depends on the particular scenario. E.g., I may imagine the case where I store returned tasks in `HashSet` and then remove them as they get completed. In which case, they have to be unique, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22493662/1768303).

Answer (score 36):

In Microsoft.net 4.6, the Task class has a static property for this purpose.

Task.CompletedTask

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask(v=vs.110).aspx