# How can I conditionally have an "async Task" method be a no-op?

Tags: c#, async-await

To get text written to the SQL Server XEvent profile, I have written the following method:

```
protected async Task LogToProfiler(string message)
{
    await using (var dbContext = await NoTrackingDbFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
    {
        await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlAsync($"-- {message}");
    }
}
```

It works great, writing out the messages where I want to the profiler event list. The problem is, what I need is:

```
#if DEBUG
protected async Task LogToProfiler(string message)
{
    await using (var dbContext = await NoTrackingDbFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
    {
        await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlAsync($"-- {message}");
    }
}
#else
protected void LogToProfiler(string message) {}
#end
```

So that in release mode there is no set up and tear down of a `Task`. Is there a way to do this?

Also, I do call it as:

```
if (profilingOn)
    await LogToProfiler("entering method");
```

Is this sufficient to avoid the setup/teardown if profilingOn == false? I believe it is. It's safer to use `#if DEBUG` but I can force `profilingOn` to false if it's built for `RELEASE`.

My fundamental concern is developers make mistakes and so it might end up being called even if profilingOn is false and we're running in `RELEASE` mode. So I want to be as safe as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return `Task.CompletedTask` without using the `async` modifier.

But `ValueTask` might be more efficient, as it doesn't set up the whole async chain if it's already completed.

```cs
#if DEBUG
protected async ValueTask LogToProfiler(string message)
{
    await using (var dbContext = await NoTrackingDbFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
    {
        await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlAsync($"-- {message}");
    }
}
#else
protected ValueTask LogToProfiler(string message) => default;
#end
```

It's a shame that the `[Conditional]` attribute isn't supported on `async Task` and `async ValueTask` methods, then you could have done:

```cs
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
protected async Task LogToProfiler(string message)
{
    await using (var dbContext = await NoTrackingDbFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
    {
        await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlAsync($"-- {message}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this for all of the log methods:

```
protected async Task LogToProfiler(Func<string> messageProvider)
{
    if(!profilerEnabled) 
       return; //as you might know this section up to await will be called synchronously.
    var message = messageProvider();
    await using (var dbContext = await NoTrackingDbFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
    {
        await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlAsync($"-- {message}");
    }
}
```

Sorry, ask @GSerg for more info how this works.

Comment: This is why SO is such a great place. Great explanation. I thought it set up the Task upon entering the method. Thank you

Comment: This explanation is not correct. "Creating a task" is [not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661428/async-stay-on-the-current-thread) as creating a thread. A `Task` is an object that will of course be created because your method is declared to return it. Calling `Task.Yield()` does not create a new thread either, what exactly happens [depends on the synchronization context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23441833/11683).

Comment: @GSerg I never said it will create thread, I just said it will run on some other in pool. Pool can consist of one thread, then you get a fool situation, usually on server mode it is more than one. As to what is returned if you invoke RunMe - Task.CompletedTask, and it is constant static stub.

Comment: Why are you suggesting to use `Thread.Sleep` in a `Task` method...

Comment: @IanKemp really? Maybe to explain something =)

Comment: @eocron My understanding was that you were referring to the use of a different thread per se. It's not important where the thread comes from. What's important is that tasks are not threads, and that whether another thread is even involved depends on the synchronization context. A synchronization context that keeps using the same thread does so not because its threadpool has been set to contain just one thread. It has a proper threadpool available to it, but it won't use it.

Comment: @GSerg No, I just showed how Task state machine works and when your code becomes "promise to execute" exactly.

Comment: @eocron It is correct that it functions in this way. It is confusing however to describe it with the words "no task will be created". Obviously a task is created, your `protected async Task` has to return it. What does not happen is invoking the state machine, which is different from creating a task. It is also not correct that "*If you explicitly call `Task.Yield()` at the start of the method it will run on some other thread in pool*".

Comment: @GSerg task is created in static constructor of Task class. No need to play with words, it is singleton, it is indeed created when you first invoke Task static methods, but lifetime is per application and not creating every time. As to Task.Yield it is specifically used for this - it's sole existence instead of plain old Task.Delay(1);

Comment: @eocron Not sure where you got that from. There is no singleton `Task`.

Comment: @GSerg Not a "complete" singleton, can return different instances on race, but none the less works the same after that. https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L1645C1-L1659C10

Comment: @eocron How is that a static constructor? That is a static property called `CompletedTask` - the one you [have been suggesting to return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78149173/how-can-i-conditionally-have-an-async-task-method-be-a-no-op/78149211?noredirect=1#comment137774767_78149211). A [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) would have been `static Task {}`, not `public static Task CompletedTask { get; }`.

Comment: @eocron The property `CompletedTask` is completely irrelevant to the entire discussion that began with [my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78149173/how-can-i-conditionally-have-an-async-task-method-be-a-no-op/78149211?noredirect=1#comment137774668_78149211). It is irrelevant if it's a "true singleton" or is created lazily. I still don't know why you brought it up, but it has nothing to do with either the fact that tasks are not threads or the fact that each task is a different instance of the class `Task`.

Comment: @GSerg I know, and this is precisely why I never said so or connected them 1-to-1. Or gone deeper in how this works under cover, because OP clearly wants to solve AOP problem, which I showed him how to solve and why this works.

Comment: @eocron Then surely you will see it appropriate to correct the two incorrect statements in your answer that I've [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78149173/how-can-i-conditionally-have-an-async-task-method-be-a-no-op/78149211?noredirect=1#comment137774855_78149211) above?

Comment: @GSerg not good with words, just trimmed answer, you are free to copy-paste-no-jutsu from wiki/official sources.